# How to add a custom user and password to run logstash successfully

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, logstash, elastic-stack

My organisation has an `ELK` setup where we push log event to `Logstash` using `Rabbitmq`. Our `Logstash` container uses custom credentials other than `guest:guest` to connect to `RabbitMQ`. We get `403` if the custom user is absent from Rabbitmq which can easily be fixed by having an entrypoint script to create the custom user (`/opt/rabbitmq/sbin/rabbitmqctl add_user cusotm_user custom_password`) in `Rabbitmq`. I am wondering is there a way to define the user in `Logstash's configuration` itself so that whenever Logstash container starts/deployed it will add the user in Rabbitmq? I would also like to know if it is a good design to create user this way.

CHeers,
DD

Comment: any suggestion, I am new to logstash and want to confirm the way to go.